# How to See Errors In IE 7

Tags: html, scripting

I am using javascript and ajax the most in my project source. All functions are working well in firefox. But some of them are not working in ie 6 and 7 browsers. Mainly Delete is not working for any page in my project. I dont know how to resolve those bugs. And dont know how to see errors in ie browsers.. So Plz help me to resolve this issue. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359#Requirements) and test your pages. Since you said you are using AJAX I think error can be javascript related.

In IE javascript errors are shown on the left hand side of the status bar (bottom).

You can also make IE show notification about error message by going to

> Tools-> Internet Options -> Advanced
>   [Tab]

and choose "Display a notification about every script error".

Please post more info about your issue.

1. What is happening when you call the "delete" function?
2. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: function confirm_delete() 
 {
       alert("hi");
    id=14;

    var deletingName=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    var con_del=confirm("Do you want to delete "+deletingName+" addressbook ?");
    if(con_del)
       {   

          window.location.href="sync.do?reqCode=deleteParticularContact&userid="+id;

        }
    else
        
          return false;   
        
}
This is what i m trying to do.Url alone not changing in ie 6 and 7

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Enable Script debugging.

Answer (score 0):

create `try-catch` statements in your code, and alert or print error messages recieved in the `catch` clause:

```
try {
    somethingThatDoesntWork();
} catch(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
```

Using this with the other tips on getting some proper debugger running should help quite a lot (: